# Joining Thread in Groovy

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, groovy

What does the `join` method do?
As in:

```
def thread = Thread.start { println "new thread" }
thread.join()
```

This code works fine even without the `join` statement.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The same as it does in Java - it causes the thread that *called* `join` to block until the thread represented by the `Thread` object on which `join` was called has terminated.

You can see the difference if you make the main thread do something else (e.g. a `println`) after spawning the new thread.

```
def thread = Thread.start {
  sleep(2000)
  println "new thread"
}
//thread.join()
println "old thread"
```

Without the `join` this println can happen while the other thread is still running, so you'll get `old thread`, followed two seconds later by `new thread`. With the `join` the main thread must wait until the other thread has finished, so you'll get nothing for two seconds, then `new thread`, then `old thread`.

Comment: So the programm won't do anything, until `thread` has finished?

Comment: @user1170330 I've added a bit more of an example.

Comment: One more question: So in my example it's actually not needed? I got it from a Groovy book.

Comment: @user1170330 if that really is your entire main program then the join makes no practical difference, but if it's the body of a method `doSomething` that can be called from elsewhere then it depends what semantics you're after - whether you want to block the code that called `doSomething` until the thread has finished or not block it.