# Groovy multi tasking

Tags: multithreading, groovy

I am trying the execute the below code in which four threads are running.

Each thread trying to add the one character to `mylist`. After each run, there should be 4 elements in the list in any order.  But, when this code is run in `jenkin` console,  getting each time different number of elements. i.e, `[A, B, Null], [C,null,D],[A,B,C,D]`.

It seem like some synchronization issue due to multi tasking. I have tried adding method add element to list using `synchronize` keyword but that didn't help.

```
class Globals {
 static def mylist=[]
 }

 class TestMultiThreadExecution implements Runnable
 {
  String name;
  public TestMultiThreadExecution(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

  //@Override
   public void run() {
   println "${name} Step 1"
   Globals.mylist.push("${name}")
 }
}

  Globals.mylist.clear() 
  Thread thread1 = new Thread(new TestMultiThreadExecution("A"));          
  thread1.start();
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(new TestMultiThreadExecution("B"));
  thread2.start();
  Thread thread3 = new Thread(new TestMultiThreadExecution("C"));
  thread3.start();
  Thread thread4 = new Thread(new TestMultiThreadExecution("D"));
  thread4.start();
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();
  thread3.join();
  thread4.join();
  println Globals.mylist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, list is being concurrently accessed and modified by 4 threads.

You can fix it by changing list type to `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as shown below.

So, the only change in the above code is to change list type in the `Globals` class. Here is the changed code snippet.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
class Globals {
  static def mylist = [] as CopyOnWriteArrayList
}
```

By the, it would be lot easier in groovy to deal with threads. May be you can refer a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370076/joining-thread-in-groovy)

Comment: FYI... The `def` in `static def mylist = [] as CopyOnWriteArrayList` is superfluous.

Comment: Glad that it helped. You may up vote in appreciation.